# RadComboBox takes a long time to expand

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, telerik, radcombobox

Q:

I use `RadComboBox` to filter my large list but i face two problems :

1- The dropdown expanding takes long time !!

2- the filtering just happens in firefox ,no filtering in internet
   explorer!!

my .aspx:

```
    <td dir="rtl">
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator18" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddl_mainLect"
         Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" InitialValue="-1" ValidationGroup="L">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_mainLect" runat="server" Filter="StartsWith" MarkFirstMatch="true"
         Width="350px" Skin="Outlook" CausesValidation="False">
        </telerik:RadComboBox>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as number one is concerned, [this documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-dropdown-opens-slowly.html) may help you.

For your second issue, are you using the most recent version of the RadControls? If not you should try upgrading.